# How can I make certain words clickable in a TextView?

Tags: java, android, regex, string, textview

I am building a twitter-like client. Assume I have a string:

`"$AAPL rocks!"`

I want to be able to click on "$AAPL" and do something.

How can I go about making $ clickable in a TextView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) should be what you are looking for.

**UPDATE:** You can implement your own URI and have your application listen for that Intent calls.

Comment: Can Linkify perform other behaviors such as opening a dialog box instead of going to the browser? There are instances where not all clickable links will be performed in the browser.